# Change ReactTable heading color using css-modules

Tags: reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules

I am not able to change the color of the header for a React table using css-modules.

My code is :

```
.CustomerTable.ReactTable .rt-thead.-header {
    color: mediumblue;
}
```

How can I do this using css-modules. As far as I know I can use the css module with the elements name, only I cannot override CSS of other modules using it.

[image: P.S added picture]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom component in the header section.

```
  const columns = [
    {
      Header:()=><span className="my_custom_class">Name</span>,
      accessor: 'name' // String-based value accessors!
    },
    {
      Header: 'Age',
      accessor: 'age',
      Cell: props => <span className='number'>{props.value}</span> // Custom cell components!
    }
  ];
```

In your style.css, import this style into your table component.

```
.my_custom_class{
  color: mediumblue;
}
```

Live Demo: [React Table](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-demo-doz88)

Comment: tried, it didn't worked...and can't we do it using css class...added image for your reference... i want to add a background color for the header row